# I want to retrieve specific columns but the amount of rows are incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my code 
i want to retrieve the positie, verloop , titel, naam, jaar
and verloop is the difference between postion of the chosen year and the year before

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTop10]
    @Jaartal int, 
    @above int
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;  

SELECT  NieuwePositie.positie, OudePositie.positie  -  NieuwePositie.positie 
as verloop, titel, naam, jaar
FROM Lijst OudePositie 
    JOIN Song ON OudePositie.songid=Song.songid
    JOIN Artiest ON Song.artiestid=Artiest.artiestid
    JOIN (SELECT songid, positie
        FROM Lijst
        where top2000jaar = @jaartal 
        GROUP BY songid, positie) AS NieuwePositie ON  NieuwePositie.songid 
        = OudePositie.songid 

where top2000jaar  = @jaartal -1
and (NieuwePositie.positie > @above)
ORDER BY positie  
END
go
execute GetTop10'2015','0'
go
```

but i only get 1703 from the 2000 rows 
http://prntscr.com/fkw37v

Comment: Presumably you want `left join` rather than `join`.  It is hard to say much beyond that without know more about the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  rebuild all indexes on these tables  and Update Statistics.